# Jmeter -GUI is hanging while recording due to large amount of data posting to DB via Api

Tags: testing, jmeter

When i'm recording through proxy server my jmeter is hanging because in our web application we are posting large amount of data to database. I have tried with increasing head size in jmeter but couldn't solve problem. Could anyone please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "hanging" doesn't tell much so consider collecting more information, to wit:

1. *jmeter.log* file contents. In the vast majority of cases it contains enough information to get to the bottom of the issue. You might also want to [increase JMeter log level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) to make it more verbose, for example to get more information on [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) add the next line to `log4j2.xml` file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
   ```
2. Take a [JVM thread dump](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options), it should reveal which threads are stuck so you will be able to at least localise the problem.

Once you have both consider either updating this question or raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)